# Laravel Error - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::gets()

Tags: laravel

I am running a query in Laravel but got this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::gets()

I have written the query

Controller

```
            $currentMonth = date('m');
            $currentmonthbilling = DB::table("billings")
                   ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
                   ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',$currentMonth)
                   ->gets();
```

View

```
<span class="info-box-number">{{ $currentmonthbilling[0]->total }}</span>
```

I expect it to display total amount for the current month

Comment: `-> gets()` should be `->get()` also I think you should use `->first()` here as you need to find single value. And in view just use as `<span class="info-box-number">{{ $currentmonthbilling->total }}</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `->get();` not `->gets();`

```
$currentmonthbilling = DB::table("billings")
                   ->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as total"))
                   ->whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = ?',$currentMonth)
                   ->get();`
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned, you should use `get()` instead of `gets()`.

But you don't need `get()` at all, and can write it more clearly.

```
$total = DB::table('billings')
    ->whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))
    ->sum('amount');
```